# Cannot ping VM hosted on Windows server from another PC machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ping, vmware-workstation, windows-domain

Here is my configuration:

1. Windows Server 2019 with Linux CentOS 7 installed on VMWare Workstation 16 Pro
2. Windows Server has domain controller
3. I'm using NAT as connection
4. I can ping the Linux from host (Windows Server)
5. I have disable ipv6 on all machines

   Windows Server Net

   ```
   IP 192.168.68.20
   Default gateway: 192.168.68.1
   Preferred DNS: 192.168.68.20
   ```

   Linux on VM

   ```
   IP 192.168.68.128
   Default Route: 192.168.68.2
   Preferred DNS: 192.168.68.2
   ```

This is my VMWare Net Configuration

[image]

When I ping the Linux from a Windows 10 (on the same domain) I get

> Destination host unreachable.

[image]

I did not find any solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM machine is behind the NAT, therefore it is "hidden" to the external network.
If you would like the VM be accessible from the LAN you will need to use `Bridged` option and have VM on the same subnet with host and other devices on the LAN.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked right after I changed it to Bridge.